# ReSharper 4.5: Code coloring options don't seem to be applied for me in VS 2008 SP1

Tags: resharper-4.5

When I go to Tools->Options->Fonts and Colors I am able to see all of the ReSharper options.  The only problem is that even when I change the color for "ReSharper Field Identifier" or "ReSharper Local Variable Identifier" it doesn't seem to do anything.  Does anyone know why that would be?

Comment: I think you should probably raise a ticket for this at JetBrain's bugtracker (http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard).

Answer (score 2):

Turn on "Use color identifiers" feature in Resharper settings.